# python azure storage entity object

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage

The Azure python API while simple and awesome lacks a bit of docu.

im using the the TableService to get an entity, as such

```
entity = self._tableService.get_entity(tableName, partitionKey, rowKey)
```

What is the returned entity?

the following blows up

```
for key in entity.keys():
```

Further is this an array of above entities

```
entities = self._tableService.query_entities(tableName, query)
```

Comment: Check it with `type(entity)` or `dir(entity)`.

Comment: yeah did an iter on the dir(entity)

Answer (score 1):

get_entity will return an instance of azure.storage.Entity with fields such as PartitionKey, RowKey and all the other fields that you've set when you added it to the table.

query_entities will return a list of azure.storage.Entity

You can add to the table 2 different ways, using a dict:

```
task = {'PartitionKey': 'tasksSeattle', 'RowKey': '1', 'description' : 'Take out the trash', 'priority' : 200}
table_service.insert_entity('tasktable', task)
```

or an azure.storage.Entity instance

```
task = Entity()
task.PartitionKey = 'tasksSeattle'
task.RowKey = '2'
task.description = 'Wash the car'
task.priority = 100
table_service.insert_entity('tasktable', task)
```

Then get_entity like this:

```
task = table_service.get_entity('tasktable', 'tasksSeattle', '1')
print(task.PartitionKey)
print(task.RowKey)
print(task.description)
print(task.priority)
```

Then query_entities like this:

```
tasks = table_service.query_entities('tasktable', "PartitionKey eq 'tasksSeattle'")
for task in tasks:
    print(task.PartitionKey)
    print(task.RowKey)
    print(task.description)
    print(task.priority)
```

There's a how-to guide that describes the basics:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/how-to-guides/table-service/

And for more advanced usage, I recommend looking at the unit tests:
https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/tests/test_tableservice.py

Comment: thats helpful if one knows the keys a priori. the test also uses known keys. i ended up doing a iteration as an object   for attr in dir(anObject):